# How to manage the regional configuration in Android app

Tags: android, android-resources

Based on the customer's country setting (which they set within the app), I need to use one of the three regional configurations. Eg: choose the regional cloud endpoint to hit.

Android supports multiple resource.xml files, but they are chosen based on locale. But in my case, I want to choose them based on a customer setting.

I can use have all the endpoint configurations in the only resources.xml file like this:

```
<resources>
    <string name="my_endpoint_us">https://usa-endpoint.mysite.com</string>
    <string name="my_endpoint_eu">https://europe-endpoint.mysite.com</string>
    <string name="my_endpoint_apj">https://asia-endpoint.mysite.com</string>
</resources>
```

And formulate the configuration name based on customer setting, but it seems clumsy:

```
myResources.getString(
    it.getIdentifier("my_endpoint" + customer.region, "string", "com.mypackage")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pass the value of the region as a parameter for your string resource

```
<string name="my_endpoint">https://%1$s-endpoint.mysite.com</string>
```

and then get the value of the endpoint like this

```
String endpoint = getString(R.string.my_endpoint, customer.region)
```

So here you only have one string in your **strings.xml** file but the weakness point here if the endpoint for each region does not have that key.

Comment: But my endpoints may not have a format that's suitable for such a placeholder replacement.